# Get the size of an upgrade with yum command

Tags: awk, upgrade, yum

I would like to get the size of a linux upgrades with `yum`.

For apt I have done this:

```
`def get_upgradable() : #récupère la list des paquets
            command = "apt list --upgradable 2>/dev/null"
            process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf8')
            packages_name = []
            for out in process.stdout :
                if "/" in out :
                    packages_name.append(out[:out.index('/')])
            return packages_name

        def get_size(*args, return_somme=True) : #fait la somme du poids de chaque paquets
            command = "apt-cache --no-all-versions show {pkg} | grep \"^Size\" | cut -d' ' -f2"
            sizes = []
            somme = 0
            for pkg in args :
                size = int(
                    subprocess.Popen(command.format(pkg=pkg), shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf8'
                    ).stdout.read())
                sizes.append(size)
                somme += size
            if return_somme : return somme
            return sizes

        somme=get_size(*get_upgradable())`
```

And I try this but I don't know, how to get only the size :

```
yum check-update | awk '/\S+\s+[0-9]\S+\s+\S+/ {print $1 }' > updates
```

Comment: Hey I posted an answer, What I understand from your question is to get size informations for packages as you clearly mentioned that. So that may be related to text processing. That is why my answer is an `awk` solution. Does this help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with a friend we work on that and upgrade the solution. Reminder : I send a python sript on server to get the upgrade size.

```
def get_upgradable() :
        if os.path.isfile("/usr/bin/apt"):
            command = "apt list --upgradable 2>/dev/null | cut -d'/' -f1"
        elif os.path.isfile("/usr/bin/yum"):
            #command = "yum check-update 2>/dev/null | grep \".x86_64\" | cut -d' ' -f1"
            command="yum check-update | awk '/\S+\s+[0-9]\S+\s+\S+/ {print $1 }'"
        else :
            raise PkgManager("Not found package manager")
            return None
        process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, encoding='utf8')
        packages_name = []
        for out in process.stdout :
            packages_name.append(out[:-1])
        return packages_name

def get_yum_size(*args, return_somme=True) :
    command = "yum info {pkg} | egrep \"(Taille|Size)\""
    factor = {"k" : 1000,
              "M" : 1000000,
              "G" : 1000000000}
    somme = 0
    sizes = []
    for pkg in args :
        lines = subprocess.Popen(command.format(pkg=pkg),
                                 shell=True,
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                 encoding='utf8',
                                ).stdout.readlines()
        infos = lines[-1][:-1].split(' ')
        size = float(infos[-2])*factor[infos[-1]]
        sizes.append(size)
        somme += size
    if return_somme : return somme
    return sizes
```

You call it with :

```
def get_size(*args, **kwargs) :
    if os.path.isfile("/usr/bin/apt"):
        return get_apt_size(*args, **kwargs)
    elif os.path.isfile("/usr/bin/yum"):
        return get_yum_size(*args, **kwargs)
    else :
        raise PkgManager("Not found package manager")
```

And in main :

```
get_size(*get_upgradable())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# yes N | yum update | awk '{if($5=="k"||$5=="M") print $1,$4,$5}' > checksize.txt
```

---

I did look at the printed result of `yum check-update` command, but there doesn't seem to include download (upgrade) size. So basically;

- Run `yum update` instead, which outputs download size infos.
- Then send key `N` beforehand to the download confirmation prompt in order to avoid any download.
- `if` statement is to avoid printing lines that doesn't contain size info.
- To print only size apart from package names just remove `$1,` from print command

**OUTPUT** (with `head` and `tail`):

```
# cat -n checksize.txt | (head; tail)
     1  centos-linux-release 22 k
     2  kernel 5.9 M
     3  kernel-core 36 M
     4  kernel-modules 28 M
     5  PackageKit 599 k
     6  PackageKit-command-not-found 27 k
     7  PackageKit-glib 140 k
     8  PackageKit-gstreamer-plugin 17 k
     9  PackageKit-gtk3-module 18 k
    10  abattis-cantarell-fonts 156 k
   886  subscription-manager-rhsm-certificates 260 k
   887  cups-ipptool 5.8 M
   888  oddjob-mkhomedir 49 k
   889  openssh-askpass 92 k
   890  python3-html5lib 214 k
   891  python3-pexpect 138 k
   892  python3-tracer 123 k
   893  elfutils-debuginfod-client 65 k
   894  kpatch-dnf 17 k
   895  memstrack 48 k
```

If you only want total download size:

```
# yes N | yum update | awk -F": " '/^Total download size/{print $2}'
1.0 G
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, that's help me. But I'have not realy the same output.

Comment: With some modifications it will work. So thank you again :)

Comment: @bastien what is the output when you run last command? Is it root privileges error?

Comment: I tried it again and it runs as expected. but it takes a while so wait a bit more

Comment: I have no output with the last command. And just :  'Taille : 951M' with the first. It's a Redhat OS.

Comment: Just change `/^Total download size/` to `/^Taille/` in awk

Comment: Yes, it was the problem. Thx.